# Jersey REST sign xml

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey, signing

I implemented my REST services using jersey. The communication layer is secured with ssl.
On the client-side i got the requirement that i should sign the xml before i call the services and verify the request on the server-side.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html

My service at the moment:

```
@POST
@Path(CONFIRM_PATH)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public ConfirmResponse confirm(ConfirmRequest request){
   // verify the signed confirm request
}
```

Client-side code (spared out to cache the service instance for readability:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.setConnectTimeout(CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
client.setReadTimeout(CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT);

URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(url).build();
WebResource service = client.resource(uri);
// sign should happen here
ConfirmResponse  response = service.post(ConfirmRequest.class, confirmRequest);
```

What is the best way to handle this?
I could simply change the type to String to get the full xml, verify it and using jaxb afterwards to get the object.
On the client-side i could also create the xml manually and post a string.

This solution sounds very disappointing to me. Any ideas?

best regards,
m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter on the outgoing request and sign it there.  Much friendlier in that you don't need to duplicate code and you have central control.